# Glitching drag&drop direction in WebGL

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to implement camera movement in WebGL project by drag&drop. I've did it via calculating differences from previous position in the event, and then this value adding to current rotation level.

Here is the piece of code which is doing the job:

```
function animate()
{
    // drag and drop part
    /*var spdx = 0, spdy = 0;
    spdy =  (HEIGHT / 2 + difference_y) / 400;
    spdx =  (WIDTH / 2 + difference_x) / 400;*/

    if(mouseDown)
    {
         camera.rotation.x += difference_x / 200;
        //camera.rotation.y += difference_y / 200;
    } 

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
    renderer.shadowMapType = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;

    object.rotation.x += 0.005;
    object.rotation.y += 0.01;

    // Render the scene.
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    //controls.update();

}

function onDocumentMouseMove(event){
    mouseX = event.clientX;
    mouseY = event.clientY;

    difference_x = mouseX - last_position_x;
    difference_y = mouseY - last_position_y;

    last_position_x = mouseX;
    last_position_y = mouseY;
}
```

It is specifically the part in animate() function up to requestAnimationFrame(animate). Variable mouseDown is set to true on ouseDown event and reset to false at mouseUp. The whole code as I have it in files you can find [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tdv64sjz/) (although it does not work in the fiddle)

To show reference properly I disable moving in one of the direction and uploaded it [here](http://asheara.andreara.net/prgf/), so you can properly test the strange behaviour.

Anyone knows where the problem might be? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was in the mouseDown event, I needed to store actual coordinates there as well.

```
function onDocumentMouseDown(event){
    mouseDown = true;
    last_position_x = event.clientX;
    last_position_y = event.clientY;
}
```